# Stratify list into unordered partitions

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm struggling to find a good algorithm for the following problem:

- Input: Unsorted list of n integers
- Output: p unsorted lists of (roughly) equal size in which each the smallest element of each list is larger than the largest element of the list before it

The goal is to stratify the output, so that, in the p = 3 case for example, I get 3 unordered lists of the small, medium and large numbers (in that order).

For example:

n = 10, p = 3

- Input: [4, 1, 8, 7, 9, 3, 6, 0, 2, 5]
- Output: [[1, 0, 2], [4, 3, 6, 5], [8, 7, 9]]

Obviously I could do this in `O(n*log(n))` time by simply sorting and then partitioning, but I'm wondering if this can't be done in in linear time. I know QuickSelect runs in expected `O(n)` average case, so my intuition is that this problem should be solvable in `O(p*n)` time.

Naively I think you could simply run QuickSelect p times, successively finding the next kth smallest element, and then performing a radix-like sort on each of the elements to partition the elements by the p pivots that were identified in the original step.

So:

1. I'm not sure the algorithm I outlined works
2. I'm not sure it
   really does take `O(p*n)`
3. Even if it is `O(p*n)`, I'm not sure
   that's an optimal complexity (though I suspect it is, because it
   seems to work in the edge cases of p = 1 and p = n)
4. It's not very
   elegant

Is there a better algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: Given your example, is `[[0], [1], [4, 8, 7, 9, 3, 6, 2, 5]]` a valid output? It can be found in O(p*n) time by finding the `p-1` smallest elements, and putting each in a singleton list, with the remaining elements in the final list. If it's not valid, your problem is underspecified.

Comment: Good point. The intention is to have the output lists be of the same size +/- 1 element. Updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickSelect is actually a partitioning algorithm, so there is no need for an extra step after QuickSelecting.

Let's suppose we have a function Partition(arr, lo, hi) which returns some `k` such that `lo <= k < hi` and rearranges `arr` such that `arr[i] <= arr[k]` if `i < k` and `arr[k] <= arr[i]` if `k < i`. Then, in essence, QuickSelect is:

```
# After this call:
#   arr[i] <= arr[med] if lo <= i < med
#   arr[med] <= arr[i] if med < i < hi
QuickSelect(arr, lo, med, hi):
  if lo < hi:
    k = Partition(arr, lo, hi)
    if med < k:
      QuickSelect(arr, lo, med, k)
    else if k < med:
      QuickSelect(arr, k + 1, med, hi)
```

That's very similar to QuickSort:

```
QuickSort(arr, lo, hi):
  if lo < hi:
    k = Partition(arr, lo, hi)
    QuickSort(arr, lo, k)
    QuickSort(arr, k + 1, hi)
```

Since QuickSelect partitions the array at the specified point (which is a bit more than just finding the relevant element), we can then easily define Stratify as a repeated call to QuickSelect:

```
Stratify(arr, n, p):
  for i from 0 to p - 2 (inclusive):
    QuickSelect(arr, floor(i * n / p), floor((i+1) * n /p, n)
```

Since QuickSelect is `O(n)`, the above Stratify is `O(p*n)`. The option of just sorting the array would take `O(n log n)`, so the above Stratify is useful if `p` is not in `O(log n)`. (Since `log n` is a small number, it may well be the case in practice that sorting is superior.)

However, it is easily possible to incorporate the stratify into QuickSelect, an algorithm which we might call QuickStratify. QuickStratify does a QuickSort exactly up to the point where the array is statified:

For convenience, a function which reports which stratum a given index falls into:

```
Stratum(i, n, p): floor(i * p / n)
```

Now:

```
QuickStratify(arr, n, p, lo, hi):
  if Stratum(lo, n, p) < Stratum(hi, n, p):
    k = Partition(arr, lo, hi)
    QuickStratify(arr, n, p, lo, k)
    QuickStratify(arr, n, p, k + 1, hi)
```

I'm pretty sure that QuickStratify is average time `O(n log p)`, but I don't have a proof handy and I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm looks good to me.  My only quibble is that I can't see how you could perform the "radix-like sorts" you talk about.  For each value x, you need to determine which of p slots it goes into, and since those slots don't seem to have a very special structure (unlike in a regular radix sort, in which they correspond to multiples of some fixed value) I think you will need O(log p) comparisons per value.

Assuming that only comparisons are used, you can't do better than O(n log n), because if you could then you could sort n numbers in better than O(n log n) just by setting p = n and running this algorithm.

Also note that if a value can appear many times, then the resulting subsets may be arbitrarily unbalanced.  (This possibility is unavoidable if you use a strict "greater than" in your condition.)

Finally, if worst-case performance is a concern, there is a [*worst-case linear* algorithm for selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians).  It has a large constant, mind you, so only consider it if your inputs are unusually patterned or come from potentially hostile sources.